# event listener that fires only when mousedown && mouseover are true

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have found many similar questions and answers like mine. Unfortunatly, I have tried to adapt those answers to fit my problem but I cannot make it work. I am making a drawing pad application. The drawing pad is made of a container full of divs. I want the color to change only when `mousedown` and `mouseover` are both true. basically, I want to click and drag my drawing lines. Im probably way out to lunch here but I am at my whits end trying things.

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
let isClicked = false;
let isHover = false;

for (box of boxes) {
  box.addEventListener("mousedown", () => isClicked = true);
}
for (box of boxes) {
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", () => isHover = true);
}

function draw() {
  if (isClicked == true && isHover == true) {
    box.target.style.background_color = "black";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to manage and track global variables, you can use the event object passed. In my example, I have a function which can make the event target black, by changing the background color. I did use the `style.backgroundColor` because `style.background-color` is incorrect for js. If the mousedown event is triggered, you can safely assume the cursor is over the element. The mouseover event does not always make the target black. Instead, I check the event property `.buttons` which will be 1 if the left mousebutton is pressed, and 0 if not. This way, I can verify if it is clicked, then we just pass the event along to our make black function.

It is possible to solve this problem by tracking global variables, however you would need to be doing a lot of "state managing" which can quickly become messy and complex. You would need a mouseout function that turns the `isHover` off, as well as a mouseup function that turns the `isClick` off. You would probably need some debouncing in case the mouseout or mouseup event didn't trigger due to a right click or the cursor being in a different position. Then you would also need to track which element `isHover` and `isClick` which is redundant in this case because we can just check the event object from our mouseover event.

```js
const boxes = [...document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item")];
const makeBlack = event => event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
function equip(box) {
  box.addEventListener("mousedown", makeBlack);
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
    if (event.buttons == 1) makeBlack(event);
  });
}
boxes.forEach(equip);
```

Comment: so, im assuming the problem is on my end some where. im really new and this is my first project beyond a simpel rock paper scissors app. when i try and run it it throws and error saying `.foreach` is not a function.

Comment: nope looks like that's my mistake, `.getElementsByClassName` doesn't have a method .forEach I just turned the result into an array so `.forEach` would be avaliable

Comment: Thank you so much! that edit fixed it. now to really scrutinize it and make sure i fully understand evberything going on!

Comment: Ironically I did something similar to your idea a while back, and you can see one issue I faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058415/chrome-can-not-drag-icon-is-interfering-with-mouseover-events-how-can-i-preve). I ended up rebuilding it with canvas [over here](https://ealop123.github.io/projects/lineDrawing/) if you want to check those out :) Was a fun learning process.

Comment: yup, haha thats pretty much what I am doing. its a project with TOP but they didn't require the click and drag drawing. It felt wrong having the only event listener be `mouseover`. Thank you so much for your help!